# Can't get Mathematica to Import PDF files with diacritics on the file name

Tags: bugs, import, files-and-directories, pdf-format, unicode

**Bug fixed in 12.2.0**

---

Tested with versions `9.0.0`, `10.0.2` and `10.3.0`, all under OS X 10.10.5. and Linux

The drag-and-drop front-end functionality also results in `$Failed`.

Surprisingly, `Import`ing, JPEGs, TXTs, and XLSX work just fine!

```
(* Initialization *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
text = "Uh oh, this could be a bug";
fileNameTemplate = StringTemplate["s`1`mple file.`2`"];
extensions = { "pdf", "txt", "jpeg", "xlsx"};

$CharacterEncoding
```

> "UTF-8"

```
(* The list of "a"s used in the test *)
Table[FromCharacterCode@a, {a, 1, 1000}];
as = Select[%, RemoveDiacritics@# == "a" &]
```

> {"a", "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "ā", "ă", "ą", "ǎ", "ǟ", "ǡ", "ǻ", "ȁ", "ȃ", "ȧ", "ɐ", "ɑ", "ɒ"}

```
(* Exporting files, no failures so far *)
Map[# -> Export[fileNameTemplate @@ #, text] &, Outer[List, as, extensions], {2}]
```

> {a,pdf}->sample file.pdf, 
> {a,txt}->sample file.txt, 
> {a,jpeg}->sample file.jpeg, 
> {a,xlsx}->sample file.xlsx
> [...]
> {ɒ,pdf}->sɒmple file.pdf, 
> [...]
> {ɒ,xlsx}->sɒmple file.xlsx

```
(* Re-importing files *)
res = Map[# -> Import@# &, GatherBy[FileNames["*file*"], FileBaseName], {2}];
Drop[res, -1];
%[[-4 ;; -3, 1 ;; 4]] // Flatten // Column
```

> sample file.jpeg-> `#image here#`
> sample file.pdf->{`#image here#`}
> sample file.txt->Uh oh, this could be a bug
> sample file.xlsx->{{{Uh oh, this could be a bug}}}
> sɐmple file.jpeg-> `#image here#`
> sɐmple file.pdf->`$Failed`
> sɐmple file.txt->Uh oh, this could be a bug
> sɐmple file.xlsx->{{{Uh oh, this could be a bug}}}

Only `PDF`s fail.
I've tried a bunch of different $CharacterEncodings, but the only solution so far was to rename the file, work with it, then rename it back, as in this (very rudimentary) example

```
withFunnyName[filePath_, fun_] := 
 Module[{origName = filePath, tempName, res},
  tempName = CreateTemporary[];
  DeleteFile[tempName];
  RenameFile[origName, tempName];
  res = fun@tempName;
  RenameFile[tempName, origName];
  res
```

]

What could I be doing wrong? Some system configurations?

Comment: This would seem to be a bug to me, and it can be tested most simply by the fact that `Import[Export["test_ǡ.png", "Hello"]]` works while `Import[Export["test_ǡ.pdf", "Hello"]]` returns `$Failed`

Comment: I suspected that, but I'm always wary of blaming the system... (You actually came! Thanks!)

Comment: Dedicated thread: "[How to workaround failures with Unicode filepaths?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143953/280)"

Comment: With *Mathematica* 12.2.0 on Windows I don't reproduce the bug aymore, so finally it seems to be fixed.