# How to workaround failures with Unicode filepaths?

Tags: bugs, import, files-and-directories, character-encoding, unicode

<sup>(Cross-posted on the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1210757), reported to the support as [CASE:3965891].)</sup>

The *Mathematica*'s Kernel and FrontEnd currently work well with Unicode file/directory paths, but some other components of the system contain long-standing bugs which are source of troubles for the users, especially for the users from non-English-speaking countries.

The most recent version of *Mathematica* 12.1 still fails to `Import` a PDF file when its path contains non-ASCII characters: under Windows `Import` returns `$Failed`, under OSX [it returns empty list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143953/how-to-workaround-failures-with-unicode-filepaths?noredirect=1#comment387154_143953). This is due to a long-standing bug in the component "PDF.exe" which is responsible for importing of PDF files:

```
Export["Тест.pdf", ""]
Import[%]
```

> ```
> "Тест.pdf"    
> $Failed
> ```

The same is true for `Import`ing *Mathematica*'s native NB files as `"Plaintext"` due to a similar long-standing bug in "NBImport.exe":

```
Export["Тест.nb", ""]
Import[%, {"NB", "Plaintext"}]
```

> ```
> "Тест.nb"
> $Failed
> ```

The new in version 11 `HTTPRequest`/`URLRead` functionality also suffer from this bug. Here is an attempt to upload an image with non-ASCII filename to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) using the method from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141853/280) answer:

```
Export["Тест.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]

URLRead[HTTPRequest[
  "http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image", <|
   "Body" -> {"image" -> <|"Content" -> File[%], "MIMEType" -> "image/png"|>}|>]]
```

[image: screenshot]

And undoubtedly there are other components suffering from this bug because reports about problems with Unicode filepaths keep appearing on this site.

Hence it is worth to have a dedicated thread with a collection of general techniques allowing to workaround such problems. This thread is intended exactly for this purpose. Some guidelines:

- When posting an OS-specific workaround, please include information about OS.
- If a workaround is limited to local file paths and doesn't work for network paths, please mention this.
- Each answer should contain elaborated description of only one general method along with its limitations.

---

Related questions:

- [Cannot import Excel (xls or xlsx) files which have non-ASCII characters in the name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76871/280)
- [11.3 - import of files with paths containing non-ASCII characters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184535/280)
- [How to deal with Chinese Windows path/filename?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140291/280)
- [Can't get Mathematica to Import PDF files with diacritics on the file name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99980/280)
- [Mathematica 10 doesn't support path containing Chinese characters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55086/280)
- [Bug in handling backslashed Cyrillic symbols in v.10.0.0?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54804/280)
- [Problem with my user name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200238/280)
- [Wrong function of NotebookDirectory[] in the 12.1 version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219700/280)

Comment: On OSX (MMA 11.1): Importing PDF with some Unicode names (e.g. ``Import["~/Тест.pdf"]``) gives the warning ``Import::general: Could not find the start of the cross reference table`` and returns an empty list `{}`. Renaming file to `test.pdf` fixes the problem.

Comment: Reported to the tech support as [CASE:3965891].

Comment: I am getting reports about MaTeX not working in some situation where the Windows username, and therefore also `$TemporaryDirectory`, have non-ASCII characters.  The root cause seems to be that `RunProcess` fails if the current directory has non-ASCII characters in its path. But I cannot reproduce this problem.  Can you?  E.g. try `RunProcess["C:\\windows\\System32\\where.exe", ProcessDirectory -> $TemporaryDirectory]` (or substitute a path with non-ASCII chars for `$TemporaryDirectory` if your username is all-ASCII).

Comment: @Szabolcs I have all-ASCII `$TemporaryDirectory` but the command `RunProcess["C:\\windows\\System32\\where.exe", ProcessDirectory -> $TemporaryDirectory]` returns `<|"ExitCode" -> 2, ...|>` (what means an error), I do not know why.

Comment: What is WRI's statement about that?

Comment: @Kuba The WRI's support response was: "<...> I have filed a report with the development team and added your contact details to the report. We hope to reach out to you once this issue is resolved in a future release of Mathematica. <...>"

Comment: `SystemOpen` seems to be broken for paths involving non-ASCII characters in _v12_, the short path trick doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, `SystemOpen` is broken in v12.0.0 but the short path trick works for me, try `SystemOpen[FileInformation[path, "AbsoluteShortFileName"]]`.

Comment: Doesn't work at least in Mma 12.0 Chinese edition, Win7 64bit. For example, `Export["测试.txt", "aaaaaa"];
FileInformation["测试.txt", "AbsoluteShortFileName"]` gives `"C:\\Users\\PC\\DOCUME~1\\测试.txt"`, and `shortPath["测试.txt"]` gives `"C:\\Users\\PC\\DOCUME~1\\\.b2âÊÔ.txt"`

Comment: @xzczd Probably it is a problem of Mma 12.0 **Chinese** edition. In my standard English version your code works correctly (and `SystemOpen` correctly opens exported file via short path). I recommend reporting this to the support.

Comment: Just tested with Wolfram Engine (12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 19, 2019)), the problem remains…

Comment: @xzczd Do you use Chinese-localized version of Windows? It can matter... In any case, try to contact the support (and share with us a solution if it exists). Good luck!

Comment: @xzczd Also try a *documented* way: `Information[File@"测试.txt", "AbsoluteShortFileName"]`.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Win 7 64bit Chinese edition. Just checked in cmd, seems that `"C:\\Users\\PC\\DOCUME~1\\测试.txt"` is exactly the correct short filename in Windows Chinese edition i.e. non-ASCII characters can be used in the short filename at least in Windows Chinese edition. (BTW if the filename is changed to e.g. `"测试测试测试测试.txt"` the output will be `"C:\\Users\\PC\\DOCUME~1\\测试测~1.TXT`. )

Comment: @xzczd Yes, it looks like short filenames really **may** contain non-ASCII characters, but it somehow should depend on the codepage used by the filesystem (it seems to be a little-known fact and I failed to find detailed information). This means that the workaround with short path isn't so reliable as I thought. Too bad... :(

Answer (score 7):

### Windows-specific: use short paths ([short filenames, 8.3 file names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename))

This method should work with all parts of the *Mathematica* system.

#### Limitations

- [short path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) can be found only for *existing* file/directory
- [short paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) exist only if generation of them isn't disabled by administrator (by default it is enabled)
- may not work for network paths
- **this method isn't reliable for localized versions of Windows** because on them the short paths allowed to contain non-ASCII characters ([example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143953/how-to-workaround-failures-with-unicode-filepaths?noredirect=1#comment520380_143953)).

#### Solutions

There is an undocumented function `FileInformation` which allows to obtain the short path (works at least starting from *Mathematica* 11.3, [thanks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143953/how-to-workaround-failures-with-unicode-filepaths#comment518433_143954) to [GenericAccountName](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38159/genericaccountname)):

```
Export["Тест.txt", ""]
FileInformation["Тест.txt", "AbsoluteShortFileName"]
```

> ```
> "Тест.txt"
>
> "D:\\DOCUME~1\\47BB~1.TXT"
> ```

Also starting from version 12.0.0 there is an under-documented (but "official") way to obtain the short path:

```
Information[File["Тест.txt"], "Properties"] // Shallow
```

> ```
> {"ObjectType", "FileName", "DirectoryName", "AbsoluteFileName", "AbsoluteShortFileName", "ShortFileName", "FileBaseName", "FileExtension", "CreationDate", "LastAccessDate", <<33>>}
> ```

```
Information[File["Тест.txt"], "AbsoluteShortFileName"]
```

> ```
> "D:\\DOCUME~1\\47BB~1.TXT"
> ```

Here is a function which expands a file/directory name and then obtains the corresponding short path using [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10227715/590388) method (tested on Windows 7 x64 but should work at least starting from Windows XP):

```
shortPath[longPath_String] /; FileExistsQ[longPath] := 
 Import["!cmd /c for %A in (\"" <> ExpandFileName[longPath] <> "\") do @echo %~sA", "Text"]
```

Another solution via `` NETLink` `` can be found in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97776/280) great answer by [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) (see also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160118/280) answer).

#### Usage

Create a PDF file with Unicode filepath and find the short path to it:

```
Export["Тест.pdf", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]
shortPath["Тест.pdf"]
```

> ```
> "Тест.pdf"
> "D:\\DOCUME~1\\FF12~1.PDF"
> ```

Import this file:

```
Import[shortPath["Тест.pdf"]]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: In v12 you can get "AbsoluteShortFileName" with FileInformation

Comment: @GenericAccountName Thank you, added to the answer. It also works in version 11.3.

Answer (score 4):

### `Import` as `"String"` first, and then apply `ImportString` or ...

Currently it is the most elegant workaround, and besides that it is expected to be OS-independent.

#### Limitations

- This method is intended exclusively for import-related tasks.
- If the path defined via `$TemporaryDirectory` contains non-ASCII characters, `ImportString` will fail because under the hood it creates a temp file in `$TemporaryDirectory` and then passes its path to the appropriate importer, hence we return back to the situation with non-ASCII file path (checked with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64). A workaround is to `Import` from a stream with `BinaryFormat -> True` (see below).

#### Solution

It is as simple as described in the head of this answer. You `Import` your file with Unicode path as `"String"` (what **works**!), and then do with the obtained string what you had to do with the original file. For example pass it to `ImportString` if your purpose was to import the file:

```
ImportString[Import[<path to PDF file>, "String"], "PDF"]
```

... or directly include it into `HTTPRequest` instead of symbolic link to the local file (see the corresponding example in the question):

```
HTTPRequest["http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image", <|
  "Body" -> {"image" -> <|"Content" -> Import["Тест.png", "String"], 
                          "MIMEType" -> "image/png"|>}|>]
```

With *Mathematica* 10 or higher instead of `Import` one can use `ReadString` what gives identical result and also is a bit faster:

```
ImportString[ReadString[<path to PDF file>], "PDF"]
```

A low-level alternative is to `OpenRead` the file with option `BinaryFormat -> True` and then `Read` it as a whole with the `RecordSeparators -> {}` option (don't forget to `Close` it afterwards!):

```
# &[Read[#, Record, RecordSeparators -> {}], Close[#]] &@
 OpenRead[fileName, BinaryFormat -> True]
```

... or directly `Import` from the stream:

```
# &[Import[#, "PDF"], Close[#]] &@OpenRead[<path to PDF file>, BinaryFormat -> True]
```

#### Usage

Import a PDF file with Unicode filepath:

```
Export["Тест.pdf", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]

ImportString[Import["Тест.pdf", "String"], "PDF"]
```

> ```
> "Тест.pdf"
> ```
>
> [image: output]

Upload an image with Unicode filepath to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/):

```
Export["Тест.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]

URLRead[HTTPRequest[
  "http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image", <|
   "Body" -> {"image" -> <|"Content" -> Import["Тест.png", "String"], 
       "MIMEType" -> "image/png"|>}|>]]
```

> ```
> "Тест.png"
> ```
>
> [image: output]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be OS-independent. On my Linux system with MMA 11.2 `Export["/tmp/тест.txt", "Hello"]` results in a file named `\:0442\:0435\:0441\:0442.txt`. Conversely, attempt at importing a correctly-named file, even with `"String"` option, results in _"Import::nffil: File not found during Import."_

Comment: @Ruslan I just have checked these on Russian-localized Linux Ubuntu 19.0.4 from Microsoft Store (under Hyper-V on Windows 10 x64) with *Mathematica* 12.0, and found that my examples as well as your are working correctly. What version of Linux do you use?

Answer (score 1):

### Works on Linux: set the environment variable `LANG` to `en_US.UTF-8`

In particular, with Mathematica installed in `~/opt/Mathematica/11.2.0`, running it in the following way appears to make `Import` and `Export` work without any special tricks:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ~/opt/Mathematica/11.2.0/Executables/Mathematica
```

When it's run as in the example above, the following commands work as intended:

```
Export["/tmp/тест.txt", "Hello"]
Import@%
```

> "/tmp/тест.txt"
>
> "Hello"

Comment: It doesn't work on Russian-localized Linux Ubuntu 19.0.4 from Microsoft Store (under Hyper-V on Windows 10 x64) with Mathematica 12.0: your last line of code produces a file with name "Ð¢ÐµÑÑÐ¾Ð²ÑÐ¹ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ð».txt".

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov funny. Maybe the difference is not with the Linux flavor/version, but with MMA 11.2 vs 12.0. I'll try 12.0 when I get to it.

Comment: I can't check with 11.2, but all the bugs described in the question are still present in version 12.0.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov just checked on a real non-virtualized Xubuntu 19.10, and it all appears to work fine in both 11.2 and 12.0, with my code behaving as you say (giving кракозябры), naïve version working as intended, and thus your answers being also unneeded. What is the output of `locale` command on your Ubuntu?

Comment: @The output is `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`.

Comment: Do you mean that the bugs described in the question aren't present in your configuration?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov with the solution I've now edited into this answer, yes, I don't have any problems with `Import` and `Export` related to Unicode filenames. The files are created and read with the correct names.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? I have little experience with Linux command-line, but was able to get the command line of Mathematica using the command `ps -p 2961 -o args` where 2961 is its PID. The output is `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica -topDirectory /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0`. Now what exactly should I do to use your technique?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov from the same terminal where you run `ps`, try running `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/Executables/Mathematica`

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is changed: the example with `Export["/tmp/тест.txt", "Hello"];
Import@%` works on my system by default, and it still works. None of the examples from the question still works as expected.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov well, indeed, the PDF and NB import still fail for some reason. But `HTTPRequest`/`URLRead` work fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I checked `HTTPRequest`/`URLRead`, but rechecking shows that it works by default on my Ubuntu system. And with your solution it works too, so it seemingly doesn't affect anything with my system configuration.