# Problem with my user name

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, files-and-directories, windows, unicode

I'm trying to use the new website ("Wolfram Function Repository") and i get the following error:

```
In[1]:= ResourceFunction["BilliardPolygon"]

During evaluation of `In[1]:= CreateDirectory::privv: Privilege violation for file or directory C:\Users\Juan Jos矁lba.`

During evaluation of `In[1]:= Put::noopen: Cannot open C:\Users\Juan Jos矁lba\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram\Objects\Resources\wordlength.`

During evaluation of `In[1]:= CreateDirectory::privv: Privilege violation for file or directory C:\Users\Juan Jos矁lba.`

Out[1]= $Failed
```

I have encountered the same problem in others occasions when i tried to use some network functionality. My guess is that Mathematica is using the wrong type of encoding for the directory name (it's called "C:\Users\Juan José Alba"), but i don't know what i can do to make Mathematica use the right directory name.

I'm using *Mathematica* 12 in Windows 10.

Any idea?

Comment: The tag "bugs" is used only when it is established that there is a bug.

Comment: I think this should be considered a bug. That clearly is not what is supposed to happen when you run the command ResourceFunction["BilliardPolygon"]

Comment: You should certainly report this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: Strongly related: "[How to workaround failures with Unicode filepaths?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143953/280)"